# .Net Core dynamically compile C# code passed in as a string

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'd like to store Code for C# Objects or Method in strings and dynamically create an object and call the method from a Parent/Main Application running in .NET Core.

Something Like:

```
methodString = @"
public bool check(string input)
{       
  return input.Length > 10;
}";

var dynamicObject = new dynamicCode.FromString(methodString);
var result = dynamicObject.Check("TestValue");
```

How could something like this be implemented in .net core

Comment: Ouch. Why on earth would you want to do this?